# Lisp expression evaluated to a list, not understanding how it works

Tags: lisp, elisp

My teacher is very bad at explaining.  He just gave us the question with an answer that he cannot explain resulting in myself not understanding much of it.

Is it possible for anyone to break down how this answer comes about?
I understand that `car` returns the first element of a list and `cdr` returns all the elements after the first element.

Thanks in advance for reading.

> Suppose the Lisp variable E has been given a value as follows:

```
(setf e '((-1 -2)
          ((90 91) 92 93 94 95 96 97 98)
          (9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89)))
```

> Write a LISP expression which doesn't involve any numbers, but which evaluates to the list:

```
(-2 91 (19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89))
```

> Answer:

```
(list (cadar e) (cadr (caadr e)) (cdaddr e))
```

Comment: That initial list is not balanced -- the closing parenthesis after `98` closes the entire list.

Comment: I've fixed the list so that (a) it's balanced, and (b) the given solution is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Common Lisp (as well as other Lisp languages) a function like `cadar` or `cdaddr` etc. (you can have up to 4 characters `d` or `a` after the first `c` and before the last `r`) is an abbreviation of a combination of the functions `car` and `cdr` with the following rule: each `a` correspond to a `car`, and each `d` correspond to a `cdr`.

In other words, `(caar x)` is equivalent to `(car (car x))`, `(caddr x)` is equivalent to `(car (cdr (cdr x)))` and so on.

So for istance, in your example `(cadar e)` means `(car (cdr (car e)))`, that is:

```
take the (car e), which is (-1 -2)
take the cdr of the previous value, which is the list (-2)
take the car of this list, that is the integer -2
```

Here the other equivalences:

```
(cadr (caadr e)) = (car (cdr (car (car (cdr e)))))
(cdaddr e) = (cdr (car (cdr (cdr e))))
```

So `(list (cadar e) (cadr (caadr e)) (cdaddr e))` is equivalent to:

```
(list (car (cdr (car e)))
      (car (cdr (car (car (cdr e)))))
      (cdr (car (cdr (cdr e)))))
```

which produces the expected result (you can verify this by applying all the functions in the correct order).

Comment: Ah, I see now!  I get the `(cadar e)` part but for some reason I can't wrap my head around `(cadr(caadr e))` and `(cdaddr e)` parts.  I tried breaking it down the way you've mentioned but it's not clicking for some reason :(.

Comment: obsolutemal: I've just **fixed** the list from the question. The bits which were confusing you might make better sense now?

Comment: e.g. The sequence which produces the second item is: `((-1 -2) ((90 91) 92 93 ...) (9 19 ...)))` cdr is `(((90 91) 92 93 ...) (9 19 ...)))` car is `((90 91) 92 93 ...)` car is `(90 91)` cdr is `(91)` car is `91`

Comment: Hmm, I kinda sorta get it now. I'm a little confused about how to know when to put the `a` in front of `d` and vice versa. If possible, may you write out the entire second item the way you did for the first? My apologies if I'm asking for too much, sir.